# Permission issue uploading files for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, permissions

I am running a Ubuntu self-managed VPS.  I've installed `wordpress` and have assigned a user `dev` to have full write and access permission through the `group` `www-data`.  Now when I go to install a theme through `wordpress` I receive a section that ask me for `FTP` credentials.  I assume this is because `wordpress` finds it is unable to write to `wp-content`?  I went ahead and assigned a `chmod 757` to the `wp-content` directory and it worked but gave me an error message: `The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2015/09.`

I have checked who owns what and so far everything seems to be owned by `dev` user and belongs to group `www-data`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chmod 757 makes it so that the group only has read and execute permissions. It is better to have it set to 775. I suspect you also didn't chmod recursively to include all subdirectories. Try this: `chmod -R 775 wp-content`.

After chatting, we also had to do `chown -R www-data wordpress` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Brian if I try this it than ask for my FTP information?

Comment: No, it's only asking for FTP information because apache doesn't have write permission to the files/subdirectories it needs.

Comment: Ohhhh, what do you recommend running?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, you just need to give apache (which by default runs as www-data) write permission to the wp-content subdirectory, and all of its subdirectories. You can do that with `chmod -R 775 wp-content` (assuming you're in the wordpress directory when you run the command).

Comment: Hmm I did just that but I still get the `FTP` information it ask for.

Comment: Can you post the permissions of `wp-content/uploads/2015/09`? You can do that with `ls -l wp-content/uploads/2015/09`.

Comment: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 947867 Sep 21 18:20 hype11.zip`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90269/discussion-between-brian-kh-and-david-biga).